# Engine Tap noise

Tags: engine, noise

I own a 2010 camry 2.5liter engine, there is a a weird noise that comes from under the hood, driver side. The engine starts nicely, however the tap sound is not heard unless the car is moved in the forward direction for about 30 seconds. And it only happens once, each time whenever I start the car the tap sound happens and goes unless the car is restarted.

This is very un usual as I dont think its knocking as its a continues sound but its my unprofessional opinion.

Comment: can you post an audio clip or video? is it a rapid clicking or is it a deeper tapping sound from the engine?

Comment: If I get this, you are saying, when you first start the car the tapping noise starts. If you then shut the car off and restart, the noise goes away?

Comment: The statement "*the tap sound is not heard unless the car is moved in the forward direction for about 30 seconds*" makes me scratch my head.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess with the limited info we have I would guess that the initial tapping is present just before oil pressure in the hydraulic valve lifters has built up enough the fully pressurise the lifter. Its normally nothing to worry about unless the tapping is becoming progressively worse,  or developing into a knock.  In which case further investigation is necessary.